# GStreamer hlssink pipeline termination

Tags: gstreamer

When playing back a local file using the following pipline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/tmp/test.mp4 ! qtdemux ! queue ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink
```

I get the following output:

```
streamer_1  | Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
streamer_1  | Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
streamer_1  | Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
streamer_1  | Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
streamer_1  | New clock: GstSystemClock
streamer_1  | Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
streamer_1  | Execution ended after 0:00:22.647824881
streamer_1  | Setting pipeline to NULL ...
streamer_1  | Freeing pipeline .
```

This pipeline works in the sense that I can see the output of the content in a browser but it terminates after 22 seconds. My test.mp4 file is a 15 minute stream.

Can someone help me to understand why it terminates when it does and how I would play the full 15 minute file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. If you introduce a `clocksync` step then it will emit frames at the expected rate:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/tmp/test.mp4 ! qtdemux ! queue ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! clocksync ! hlssink
```